# proving equality between spanners in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Hey and thank you for reading and helping,

i am having trobule with proving an equation between two spanners (Sp). 
the question is:
given two subspaces of $ R^4$ :

U = Sp{(2,5,-4,-10),(1,1,1,1),(1,0,3,5),(0,2,-4,-8)}.
W = Sp{(1,-2,7,13),(3,1,7,11),(2,1,4,6)}

a)prove that U = W
b)v=(a,a-6,4a-3,6a-1). find the values of a so v will belong to U.

what i tried to do:

a)i tried to find a linear connection between U and W to show that there is a linear dependency, but i did not succeed. does it matter if U has one more coordinate that W?
b)again, tried to represent v as a linear combination that will equal to given vectors in u, but i don't think it's correct.

can you please help me and show me the correct answer and how to write it?

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, find basis of $U$ and $W$. If they dimensions will be different then the subspaces cannot be equal, but in this case $\dim U=\dim W = 2$.
To show $U=W$ you can show that $U\subset W$ and $U\supset W$. To show first inclusion you take any vector from $U$, which in general looks like $a(1,0,3,0)+b(0,1,-2,0)$ (these vectors form basis of $U$) and show that it can be represented as linear combination of basis vectors from $W$. Then you do similar thing for $U\supset W$, you take any vector from $W$ and show it's linear combination of vectors from $U$.

For the second part, you have to find $c,d$ such that $(a,a-6,4a-3,6a-1)=c(1,0,3,0)+d(0,1,-2,0)$, which requires just solving a system of linear equations.

Comment: i might be doing this for too many hours, but i don't understand this:
"a(1,0,3,0)+b(0,1,−2,0) (these vectors form basis of U)", if the vectors span U, aren't they create the base of the basis of U? i don't understand the procedure. can you please explain it?

Comment: @linearproblems I don't understand your question, try to reformulate it. $U$ is spanned by four vectors, but two of them are linearly dependent, $(1,0,3,0),(0,1,−2,0)$ is a base I found through row reducing the matrix whose rows are vectors from the span. Now, $\mathrm{span} \{(2,5,-4,-10),(1,1,1,1),(1,0,3,5),(0,2,-4,-8)\} = \mathrm{span}\left\{(1,0,3,0),(0,1,−2,0)\right\}$, which, by definition of span means that every vector $v$ in $U$ can be written as $a(1,0,3,0)+b(0,1,−2,0)$ for some real $a, b$.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to show that two sets $U$ and $W$ are equal is to prove that $U\subseteq W$ and $W\subseteq U$. Recalling that the image (range) of a matrix is its column space, both of these inclusions can be verified via row-reduction. First, build the matrix that contains the given spanning vectors of $U$ and then the spanning vectors of $W$ as columns, and then reduce this matrix to echelon form. If every row that has all zeros on the left side also has zeros on the right, this means that every one of the spanning vectors of $W$ is an element of $U$, and so also $W\subseteq U$. To prove the inclusion in the other direction, put the spanning vectors of $W$ on the left and those of $U$ on the right and row-reduce again.

The second part of the problem can be solved in the same way: augment either set of spanning vectors with $v$ and row-reduce, then choose a value of a that makes the system of equations represented by this matrix consistent, i.e., that every row which starts with all zeros also has a zero in the last column. You might find in doing the first part that the dimension of $U$ is less than the number of spanning vectors given in the problem, in which case you only need to use a subset of them for this part.